# How to reopen the response/request view in Network tab of Chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

On the network tab, usually when you click a specific network request, you get a view which gives more detail: the headers, the request, the response, etc.

But if I close this view by clicking the X, I can't find a way to reliably get it back again:

[image]

Clicking on a row doesn't do it. What am I missing? How do I get the detail view back?